# Singleton with NSTimer not firing from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, nstimer, appdelegate

I'm trying to get a singleton with an `NSTimer` to fire from within my `AppDelegate` so that it fires for the duration of whilst the app is running. Whilst I can make it work in Objective-C, I can't seem to make the link as to why it's not working in Swift. Every 30 seconds I want it to poll a server and download any messages that are waiting.

The code I have in my **AppDelegate** is:

```
var myGetMessages:GetMessages!

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    ..lots of other things ..

    myGetMessages = GetMessages.sharedInstance
    myGetMessages.downloadMessages()
}
```

My **Singleton** has:

```
class GetMessages {

static let sharedInstance = GetMessages()

var messageDownloadTimer: NSTimer?

.. other init code ....

func downloadMessages() {
    if myMainUser != nil {
        if messageDownloadTimer == nil {
            self.getMessagesFromServer(false, completionHandler: nil)
            messageDownloadTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 30, target: self, selector: "downloadNewMessages", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    } else {
        println("There is no MainUser set up, so can't download Messages")
    }

}
```

It fires once from the AppDelegate and then never again.

Any clue as to what I'm missing would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your download function;

```
func downloadMessages() {
    if messageDownloadTimer == nil {
         //?? messageDownloadTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 30, target: self, selector: "downloadNewMessages", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
         messageDownloadTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(30, target: self, selector: "downloadNewMessages", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    //--
    if myMainUser != nil {
       self.getMessagesFromServer(false, completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        println("There is no MainUser set up, so can't download Messages")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'd obviously missed the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`. I also needed to add to my class the : `NSObject` as the `NSTimer` wasn't then finding the `downloadNewMessages` method. You've been a great help.